# In zend, how to print a mysql query properly?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to print exact sql query in zend framework ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723657/how-to-print-exact-sql-query-in-zend-framework)

In zend profiler, I can only either print the query with question markers (getQuery) or print the parameter array (getQueryParams).

Is there a way to replace all question markers, and print the real sql query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Something like that should work:

```
$profile = $this->getQueryProfile($queryId);
$query = $profile->getQuery();
$params = $profile->getQueryParams();

      foreach ($params as $par) {
            $query = preg_replace('/\\?/', "'" . $par . "'", $query, 1);
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

The framework uses prepared statements so actually this is the real query - in reality its send to the database which parses it and then the params are binded to it and executed.

Comment: I am also in the same situation, i have the values with "?" or the values are in array format and not in sql statements..is there any way to have it like INSERT INTO 'table' ('','','') VALUES ('','','')

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `__toString()` method.

```
$dbTable = new Application_Model_DbTable_TradeshowBooking();
$select = $dbTable->select();
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$select->where('ends_on + INTERVAL 4 WEEK > ? ', $requestParams['ends_on']);        

Zend_Registry::get('logger')->log($select->__toString(), Zend_Log::INFO);
```