# php zend framework log mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am trying to log the sql queries when a script is running. I am using zend framework and I already checked zend db profiler and this is not useful as this shows "?" for the values in a insert query..I need the actual values itself so that I can log it in a file. I use getAdapter()->update method for the update queries so I don' know if there is a way to get queries and log it. Please let me know if there is  a way to log the queries.

regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.profiler.html

> The return value of `getLastQueryProfile()` and the individual elements of `getQueryProfiles()` are `Zend_Db_Profiler_Query` objects, which provide the ability to inspect the individual queries themselves:
>
> - **`getQuery()`** returns the SQL text of the query. The SQL text of a prepared statement with parameters is the text at the time the query was prepared, so it contains parameter placeholders, not the values used when the statement is executed.
> - **`getQueryParams()`** returns an array of parameter values used when executing a prepared query. This includes both bound parameters and arguments to the statement's execute() method. The keys of the array are the positional (1-based) or named (string) parameter indices.

When you use `Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug` it will also show you the queries on the returned pages in the Firebug console along with any bound parameters.

Comment: thanks @Gordon, but I am going to run it from command line, so I cannot see it in firebug..any other way?

Comment: @Jay yes, use `getQueryParams()` like it says in the quotation.

Comment: I used this but it just shows Array when i run the script..but when i use getQuery(), i see the sql statements

Comment: sorry I should have been clear, I used print_r but I see the array with values like Array( [1]=>test [2]=>name....)..its not showing the values as in a query so that I can copy the queries..with getQuery() it shows like INSERT INTO....

Comment: @Jay yes, you have to do that by hand. The bound parameters are not inserted into the query before it gets executed. This only happens inside your database system.

Comment: thanks..so no way to get the query statements directly that I can log..thanks again

Comment: someone had the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712669/in-zend-how-to-print-a-mysql-query-properly, so I am not sure if there is any alternative solution for this..

Comment: @Jay well, yeah. That's what I meant when I said "the bound parameters are not inserted into the query".

Answer (score 3):

I know you have got your answer though just for reference...
I have traversed hundred of pages, googled a lot but i have not found any exact solution.
Finally this worked for me. Irrespective where you are in either controller or model. This code worked for me every where. Just use this

```
//Before executing your query
$db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
$db->getProfiler()->setEnabled(true);
$profiler = $db->getProfiler();

// Execute your any of database query here like select, update, insert
//The code below must be after query execution
$query  = $profiler->getLastQueryProfile();
$params = $query->getQueryParams();
$querystr  = $query->getQuery();

foreach ($params as $par) {
    $querystr = preg_replace('/\\?/', "'" . $par . "'", $querystr, 1);
}
echo $querystr;
```

Finally this thing worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few logs MySQL keeps itself.

Most notably:

The binary log (all queries)
Slow query log (queries that take longer than x time to execute)

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-logs.html

Comment: +1 I prefer this way as well, though I don't think it would show the actual values, if prepared statements were used.

Comment: @Adrian, the binary log holds all values of all update and insert statements. It handles prepared statements correctly and stores them in the binlog as they are eventually executed.